# How to use MongoDB 4.0 Multi-document ACID transactions with Meteor 1.8

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Been trying to do it this way: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/3051150f2f5ae953f391802e73682fba613b3d46/packages/mongo/mongo_livedata_tests.js#L3431-L3487

but getting a lot of errors like:

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Given transaction number 5 does not match any in-progress transactions.

I am using the following code:

collection.js contains the following helper function to wrap db commands in transactions elsewhere (this is all on the server side):

```
const { client } = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;

export const RunInMongoTx = async function(func) {
      try {
        const session = await client.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        options = { session };

        func(options);

        session.commitTransaction();
      } catch (error) {
        session.abortTransaction();
        throw error;
      }
    };
```

In other files, I then import the function and use it:

```
import {RunInMongoTx} from "./collections";

Meteor.methods({
  "ShiftRequests.setAsDidNotTurnUp": sr => {
    const job = Jobs.findOne({ _id: sr.jobId });
    if (job.poster != Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(
        "not-job-poster",
        "Only poster can setAsDidNotTurnUp"
      );
    }

    RunInMongoTx(async options => {
      res = await EmployerFeedbacks.rawCollection().remove(
        {
          jobId: job._id,
          workerId: sr.workerId
        },
        options
      );

      res = await ShiftRequests.rawCollection().update(
        { _id: sr._id },
        { $set: { didNotTurnUp: true } },
        options
      );
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: The `rawCollection` calls are not part of the Meteor environment. I always bind these external calls with the Meteor env using [Meteor.bindEnvironment](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#bind-environment). Does this bring you any further?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you are calling the RunInMongoTx function without await.

```js
const { client } = MongoInternals.defaultRemoteCollectionDriver().mongo;

export const RunInMongoTx = async function(func) {
      try {
        const session = await client.startSession();
        session.startTransaction();
        options = { session };

        await func(options);

        session.commitTransaction();
      } catch (error) {
        session.abortTransaction();
        throw error;
      }
    };
```

```js
import {RunInMongoTx} from "./collections";

Meteor.methods({
  "ShiftRequests.setAsDidNotTurnUp": async sr => {
    const job = Jobs.findOne({ _id: sr.jobId });
    if (job.poster != Meteor.userId()) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(
        "not-job-poster",
        "Only poster can setAsDidNotTurnUp"
      );
    }

    await RunInMongoTx(async options => {
      res = await EmployerFeedbacks.rawCollection().remove(
        {
          jobId: job._id,
          workerId: sr.workerId
        },
        options
      );

      res = await ShiftRequests.rawCollection().update(
        { _id: sr._id },
        { $set: { didNotTurnUp: true } },
        options
      );
    });
  }
});
```

Let me know if this worked.

Comment: I made these changes. Now there is no error but unfortunately, the writes do NOT happen on Mongo either. Is this something to do with the way Meteor Fibers works and its interaction with await/async? Because Meteor uses Fibers inside Meteor.methods to simulate synchronous code execution

Comment: Sorry I think it is working - I am using redis-oplog and rawCollection would bypass the hooks that redis-oplog uses hence I did not see the data changes happening in the app - give me a few mins while I monitor the actual MongoDB db with external tools, will get back to you  ASAP

Comment: Yes this solution works - thank you so much :) I need to do more reading on async/await!

Comment: Awesome, I also use redis-oplog and you are right it misses this kind of ops. Theres a way of making this automatically using another program called oplogtoredis

https://github.com/tulip/oplogtoredis

Comment: the bottom of this page provides specific guidance on using rawCollection with redis-oplog: https://github.com/cult-of-coders/redis-oplog/blob/master/docs/outside_mutations.md

Comment: Out of curiosity do you plan to make all your writes go through transactions (or are you using MongoDB 3?)

Comment: Im using Latest mongo, but no. Not all will be transactions, in our case is not necesary for all our operations. Just the ones that require multiple docs to be updated and that data needs to be consistent between collections or other docs.

Comment: using the type of code above, I can perform transactions involving multiple remove,updates and  inserts ok, however, I cannot do any transactions that find() then insert() - the find() fails in various ways like"TypeError: final argument to `executeOperation` must be a callback" or " Error: ClientSession cannot be serialized to BSON." - its seems to be a problem with the version of the mongo driver being used by meteor being too old and not accepting the options object containing the { session } as the last argument